# Selenium: Click on tag by title using XPath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Need some help on Xpath for following code:

```
<span class-"metadata-row float-left" style="width: 1.9vw;"> &absp; </span>
<input placeholder="New Course Name" id="newCourseName" type="text” class="metadata-name metadata-name-edit font-12" autofocus>
<span class="fa fa-check metadata-action-icon" title="Save" onclick="addCourse(this)" style="display: block;"> ... </span>
```

I want to click on "Save" which is mentioned as title in the code but in ui it is showing as icon.

Comment: Add code as text not as link to an image.

Comment: yeah thanks. i'll take care ahead

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the element with *title* attribute as **Save** you need to use `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.fa.fa-check.metadata-action-icon[title='Save']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='fa fa-check metadata-action-icon' and @title='Save']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: "Thanks", i have tried the first one but getting exception Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: span.fa.fa-check.metadata-ok.metadata-action-icon[title='Save'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: @virsoftech Seems you have replaced the html image with text based HTML and the DOM is changed. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: sir i am getting : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //span[@class='fa fa-check metadata-action-icon' and @title='Save'] (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
 at test.Utils.saveIcon(Utils.java:51)
 at test.AdminHomePage.questionWindow(AdminHomePage.java:144)
 at test.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:59)

Answer (score 0):

try javascript executor

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);